# Metadata exception - schema specified is not valid - Installing a C# Windows Forms application on Windows XP using ClickOnce and EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework-5, clickonce

I have a C# [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application that makes use of [SQL Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2008) R2, .NET Framework 4, .NET Framework 4 Client, and [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) [Code First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh126815.aspx).

SQL Server 2008 R2 Express exists on the machine, and the program does create the database and tables.

[image: Here is a screen dump of the message]

[Update]
I tried installing .NET framework 4.5, but I got this message:

> Blocking Issues: 
>   The .NET Framework 4.5 is not supported on this operating system.
>   
>   
>   
>   Warnings: 
>   
>   Setup may not run properly, because the Windows Modules Installer
>   Service is not available on this computer.

[with this link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/1/C/11CC285A-F710-4B77-AC98-E17E3CA1C009/Net%20Framework%204.5%20Readme_enu.htm)

The operating system is Windows XP 2002 SP3 running inside [VMware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware) Player.

[Update 25th May 20xx]: I found a link [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2012/10/16/setup-exe-is-not-a-valid-win32-application.aspx) that caused me to think the problem is just that [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) won't install on Windows XP. However I recreated the set up in Visual Studio 2010 and have the same error.

[update 26 May 20xx]: I created a test project with Visual Studio 2012 and [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) 5 and was able to successfully install on Windows XP using ClickOnce. Strangely I was then able to publish a version of my big application that worked.
I am not sure what is going on. I also did install a program containing Entity Framework 6 on my test computer - but this would not have been referenced by my big application.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing .NET 4.5?

I know it sounds absurd, but we're seeing the same issue: Entity Framework 5.0 (4.4) targetting .NET 4.0, Code First on SQL Server CE.

Installing .NET 4.5 made the issue go away. We're still investigating, because we also have a couple of Windows XP clients.

**Update:**
Portions of the Entity Framework 5 code are part of the .NET framework itself (that's why there's a 4.4 version for .NET 4.0 that e.g. doesn't support enums, while the 5.0 for 4.5 does).

It seems this issue is related to that since installing .NET 4.5 inexpliccably solves this.

For Entity Framework 6 those portions were moved to Entity Framework, so Entity Framework 6 doesn't depend on framework specifics anymore. We've updated to Entity Framework 6.0 alpha 3 and everything seems fine.

Now, I don't like running alpha code, but this is the only solution we could find.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @m_i . I updated the question with what happened when I tried it.

Comment: Ah, it's XP, so .NET 4.5 is not option.

If .NET 4.5 is installed our application uses msvcr110_clr0400.dll instead of msvcr100_clr0400.dll. That's the only difference I could spot. 
Haven't been ably to deploy msvcr110_clr0400.dll to a .NET 4.0 machine though.

Comment: Sorry I missed your update earlier - I will check it out. I am also updating my question

Comment: I am awarding you the bounty -because your comments helped me